# Issue while transposing a matrix in javascript

Tags: javascript

I made a basic function which creates a new matrix which is rotated (transpose) of the input matrix.

```
let suggestionsArray = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16]]
            const keySize = suggestionsArray.length;
            const colSize = suggestionsArray[0].length
            let matrix = Array(colSize).fill(Array(keySize))
            console.log(matrix)
            for (let i = 0; i < keySize; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < colSize; j++) {
                    
                    matrix[j][i] = suggestionsArray[i][j]
                    console.log(j, i, matrix[j][i])
                }
            }
            console.log(matrix)
            return matrix
```

But the result matrix is

```
[
    [
        4,
        8,
        12,
        16
    ],
    [
        4,
        8,
        12,
        16
    ],
    [
        4,
        8,
        12,
        16
    ],
    [
        4,
        8,
        12,
        16
    ]
]
```

Which is not something I was expecting

I've ready playing around but and everything looked good to me but still the matrix comes up wrong.

Comment: `fill` takes a constant value and this is an array which keeps the same object reference. use `map` with a new array instead.

Comment: Can you please tell us exactly what you mean by "rotate the matrix"? What is the result you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are trying to "transpose" the matrix, then the following would do it:

```js
let suggestionsArray = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12],
  [13, 14, 15, 16]
]
const matrix=suggestionsArray.reduce((ma,row,i)=>{
 row.forEach((cell,j)=>(ma[j]??=[])[i]=cell);
 return ma;
},[])

console.log(matrix)
```

Comment: It works! But would love to know how come my solution wasn't working out

Comment: @NinaScholz nailed it already: The argument of your `.fill()` method is calculated *before* it then spreads it as *one and the same object* (in this case an array) over the array elements to be filled. When you then assign values to this array they will be seen multiple times! It should work if you replace `Array(colSize).fill(Array(keySize))` with `[...Array(colSize).keys()].map(_=>[])`